# How to make an API request in Flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter

I'm new to Flutter, so I'm not sure how I am supposed to make an API call, coming from Java where I was using Retrofit.

JSON Response:

```
{
    "total": 13,
    "rows": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Name"
        }
    ]
}
```

Model class:

```dart
class Category {
  int total;
  List<Rows> rows;
  Category({this.total, this.rows});

  Category.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    total = json['total'];
    if (json['rows'] != null) {
      rows = new List<Rows>();
      json['rows'].forEach((v) {
        rows.add(new Rows.fromJson(v));
      });
    }
  }
}
class Rows {
  String name;
  Rows({this.name});

  Rows.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    name = json['name'];
  }
}
```

Main class

```
List<Rows> rows = [];


  Future<List<Rows>> getData() async {
    var response = await http.get(
        Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.0.10/api/v1/categories"),
        headers: {
          "Authorization": "API",
          "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    );
    var jsonData = json.decode(response.body);
  }
```

I'm not sure how to approach I tried getting the object with Rows.fromJson(), but I only get 'Instance of Rows' and by calling name I get null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach is correct but for list you should use list.map for deserializing lists.

Try this, I didn't tested it, I just wrote it looking at your examples

```
var response = await http.get(
    Uri.encodeFull("http://192.168.0.10/api/v1/categories"),
    headers: {
      "Authorization": "API",
      "Accept": "application/json"
    }
);
List<Rows> rows = [];

Map map = json.decode(response.body);
List l = map["rows"];
rows = l.map((map) => Rows.fromJson(map)).toList();
```

Comment: Thanks so much, that worked perfectly. Could you explain to me this line?
 rows = l.map((map) => Rows.fromJson(map)).toList(); What is exactly => Rows.fromJson(map)).toList();

Comment: It's because `json.decode(..)` deserialize json to a `Map` object and an array in json is deserialized to a `List<Map>`.  When you access `map["rows"]` you get a List (implicitly List of Maps). So you need to transform all the maps in the list into object of different type. That is done with the `list.map(..)` function. With the 'map' function every object in the list is used to create a new object with `Rows.fromJson(..)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use [json_serializable](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable) and [json_annotation](https://pub.dev/packages/json_annotation) and [build_runner](https://pub.dev/packages/build_runner)